# What is a salesforce sandbox?

Tags: salesforce

I keep seeing the sandbox 'switch' every time I log into salesforce, no matter which environment I'm logging into (prod and pre envs usually).

What's a sandbox in salesforce? What does it mean to use a sandbox or not using it?

Additionally, on libraries like https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk or https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce, sandbox is a boolean which you specify to log into it.

Is it equivalent to an autocommit connection (regarding relational databases)?

Answer (score 2):

A sandbox is a separate environment from the main production environment that copies the configuration (and sometimes data, depending on the type of sandbox), and is designed to be used for development, testing or training.

When logging in, you need to specify whether the environment you are logging into is a sandbox because the sandbox login service is hosted at a separate domain; `test.salesforce.com` vs `login.salesforce.com`.

A sandbox isn't related to an autocommit connection. I would say it is equivalent to a development environment or a test environment.

For more information, I would recommend looking at the [Development Lifecycle Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox is in short: It is Dev or Test or Integration environment for your production.
It is always recommended to develope your code in Sandbox then deploy it to production.

Refer the trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/declarative-change-set-development/plan-for-changes-to-your-org